# What’s the difference between “Anschlag” and “Angriff”?

Tags: difference, meaning

*Anschlag* and *Angriff* both seem to have the meaning of *attack,* but what are their differences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both terms have other meanings as well, but in the sense of ‘attack’ or ‘assault’, their differences may be summarized as follows:

- A singular destructive event without consequent action is an *Anschlag*, e.g. in terrorism.
- When it is possibly met by *Verteidigung* ‘defense’ it is an *Angriff*, e.g. in war, sports and chess.

An *Angriff* is also more likely to be considered legitimate or legal by the author than an *Anschlag*.

> Die USA reagierten auf die von Al-Kaida verübten **Terroranschläge** vom 11. September 2001 mit einem militärischen **Angriff** auf die in Afghanistan herrschenden Taliban.

Comment: When there is no defense, I'd say it is just as much an "Angriff" (albeit a very easy and quickly decided one).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It can be an _Angriff_ without a battle ensuing, but a (successful) _Anschlag_ is never followed by a fight. A _Gegenschlag_ ‘counter-attack’ may follow, though. It’s also in the word roots: _greifen_ implies a longer lasting action (with _halten_) than _schlagen_.

Answer (score 2):

Very good question! I am a native speaker and my initial reaction was that "Angriff" is the general term, while "Anschlag" has to be morally condemnable.

Anschlag often describes covert terrorist activities, but I think the covert nature is not essential. **I think that originally the essential element was the destructive character**, as suggested by Duden's definition:

> gewalttätiger, auf Vernichtung, Zerstörung zielender Angriff

I am not sure, how much this definition reflects everyday usage, because I would not hesitate to call a killing with a syringe a "Mordanschlag". Such a killing is not "destructive", but can be connected with "Vernichtung".

There are also many meanings of "Anschlag" that don't relate to attacking.

Comment: I _would_ (also as a native speaker) call a murder by poison injected with a syringe "Mordanschlag" but upvoted your answer because I prefer your broader definition of "Anschlag" which I think is important in describing the term. My reason is that e.g. in war you might want to cripple the enemy's capabilities by sabotaging some of their infrastructure (say, a bridge) which I would then call "einen Anschlag auf die Brücke", without there being any objective connotation of terrorism, since it's a war situation. (Edit: also see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschlag)

Comment: @RainerVerteidiger Thank you and fully agreed! That's what I too am saying, "ich würde nicht zögern es einen Mordanschlag zu nennen".